# deleting rows that has a particular date in the date1 column

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have to delete rows which has a particular date "2019-10-07" which in the column "date1". Date object is not working with the given code.

I have tried 2 codes but it seems like its not working for my dataframe. I have attached my dataframe below, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrIC-ZY1mjKGpGdH9OT83EPzHBcvCUMo/view?usp=sharing

I have been using these codes but its not working

```
df1.drop(df1.loc[df1['date1']== "2019-10-07"].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Use `df1 = df1[df1['date1'] != '2019-10-07']`

Comment: logic is select all rows if not `2019-10-07` in `date1`

Comment: this code also didnt work, can you please check with this dataframe?

Comment: tested  and working nice.

Comment: `df1 = pd.read_csv('aaaa.csv', index_col=0)

df1 = df1[df1['date1'] != '2019-10-07']`

Comment: yes its working with this. 
But actually I am creating date1 column in the code itself and then applying this code, then its not working.

Comment: wait i will post another question based on my initial code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201501/discussion-between-anadi-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df1 = df1[df1['date1'] != '2019-10-07']
```

This way you select all the rows that are not `'2019-10-07'`

Comment: this code also didnt work.  Can you please check?

Comment: @anadi Instead of saying it doesn't work. Could you post the error message?